# docker build taking too much time in aws ecs

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, docker, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I have setup master and slave configuration of jenkins on aws ecs. Written a job that will build docker images and push to ecr. So each time the job builds it is taking the same amount of time approx to 10 min. My jenkins master is running on container and and have used Amazon EC2 Container Service Plugin to configure slave. I have mounted the docker socket file so that the slave node will have access to docker daemon but it is not using the layer images of the ecs instance. Each time it starts from fresh.

Overview of each build:

[image]

Comment: 1. Does this build take significantly less time after the first run in your local machine? 2. How many EC2 instances are there in your ECS cluster? 3. Have you changed any of the default ECS agent configuration values?

Comment: Can you show the logs for this step?

Comment: I am experiencing the same, have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your docker build is not using caching mechanism of docker. Please refer [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#build-cache) for building cache.